# Getting error - Server Error SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: next.js

When I navigate to a page using router.push("/ViewMap"); it navigates to that page. But if I access that page using http://localhost:3000/ViewMap I get Server Error.
`import { jsxs as f, jsx as o } from "react/jsx-runtime";
^^^^^^

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at mod.require (C:\Users\262294\Desktop\Daimaru\area_management_tools\node_modules\next\dist\server\require-hook.js:64:28) 
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at mui-file-input (C:\Users\262294\Desktop\Daimaru\area_management_tools\.next\server\pages\ViewMap.js:470:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\262294\Desktop\Daimaru\area_management_tools\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)       
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/components/commons_menu/entry_area_info/entry_unit.tsx:45:72)
    at ./src/components/commons_menu/entry_area_info/entry_unit.tsx (C:\Users\262294\Desktop\Daimaru\area_management_tools\.next\server\pages\ViewMap.js:107:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\262294\Desktop\Daimaru\area_management_tools\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)       
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/components/commons_menu/entry_area_info/entry_area_info.tsx:14:69) {
  page: '/ViewMap'
}`
```

[error while using the page directly through URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldA9Z.png)

How can I access the page directly using URL.
The page which I am trying to use is .tsx file
This is a next.js project